# sizeof pointer and variable is not the same

Tags: c

why value a and x is different? I think it should be the same

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   
  int a =5;
  int *x=&a;

  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(a)); // print 4
  
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(x)); // print 8
   
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think they *would* be the same?

Comment: A pointer must be large enough to be able to point to all possible memory addresses. On 64-bit systems, this will tend to be 8 bytes.

Comment: @dbush: Surely you'd never need more than 256 different `char*`s in your entire program! ;-)

Comment: Sidebar: the correct `printf` field descriptor for a `size_t` (the type of the result of `sizeof`) is `%zu`.

Comment: On any given system the size of a pointer is the same no matter what type it points to. Variables of various types---`char`, `int`, `long`, etc.--- may be different.

Comment: @jkb: That is actually not quite correct. The ISO C and ISO C++ standard [allows pointers to different types to be of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71870205/12149471). Historically, there have actually been cases where pointers to different types were actually handled differently and had different sizes. However, I have never encountered such a system myself, I have only read about them.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Systems with different sizes for objects pointers vs. function pointers are not unusual these days. Perhaps you have come across those?

Comment: @JohnFilleau "A pointer must be large enough to be able to point to all possible memory addresses.' --> C does not require that - counter and historic examples exist.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks -- I'm going to leave my comment up so your response makes sense in context.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are aware of what you are actually measuring with the `sizeof` operator.

First you measure integer `a`, which is the size of an `int` (4 bytes).
And second you measure not an integer but a pointer which stores the address of integer `a`, so the value is different and I think the value of `x` is 8 bytes.

- `int a` (4 bytes INTEGER)
- `int *x = &a` (is address of `a`)

But I can be wrong.

Comment: On a 64-bit system, the value of a pointer is normally 8 bytes, but on a 32-bit system (or in a 32-bit executable running on a 64-bit system), the size of a pointer is normally 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> why value `a` and `x` is different? I think it should be the same

`a` is an `int` and `x` is a pointer.

```
int a = 5;
int *x = &a;
```

C does not specifier an `int` and a pointer need to be the same size.  They *may* have the same size.  Commonly a pointer is as wide as an `int` or wider, yet either one may be wider than the other.

It is implementation defined.

---

Since C99, use `"%zu"` to print a `size_t`, which is the resultant type from `sizeof`.

```
// printf("%ld\n", sizeof(a));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
// or 
printf("%zu\n", sizeof a); // () not needed about objects.
```