# Type deduction for a member function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, c++20

I know there are similar questions on SO, but the usages there seem different to what I have. Here is my MRE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void freeFunction() {}

struct Foo { void memberFunction() {} };

template<typename FunctionPtrT>
void foo(FunctionPtrT* f) { f(); }

template<typename InstanceT, typename FunctionPtrT>
void bar(InstanceT&& i, FunctionPtrT f) { std::mem_fn(f)(i); }

template<typename InstanceT, typename FunctionPtrT>
void baz(InstanceT&& i, FunctionPtrT* f) {}

int main() {
  foo(&freeFunction); //Ok, obviously
  bar(Foo(), &Foo::memberFunction); //Ok, how?!
  // Error: candidate template ignored: could not match 'FunctionPtrT *' against 'void (Foo::*)()'
  baz(Foo(), &Foo::memberFunction); //why?!
  return 0;
}
```

Why is `&Foo::memberFunction` not resolving to a pointer? What is the type of `f` in `bar`? If it's not a pointer how am I able to pass it to `std::mem_fun` that is defined as `template< class M, class T > /*unspecified*/ mem_fn(M T::* pm) noexcept;`?

Comment: A member function pointer isn't a pointer, they're separate types

Comment: Loosely formulated : A member function pointer also needs information on the instance of the class. Thus it is a more complex type then a normal function pointer.
You will get something like `template<typename retval_t, typename class_t, typename... args_t> void foo(retval_t class_t::*method(args_t...))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General suggestion for type investigations

I think the easiest way to answer questions like "what is the type of `x` in *this context*" is to put a `static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, delctype(x)>);` in that same context. The compiler will then tell you the `static_assert`ion failed because `void` is not equal to the type of `x`, revealing what that type is.

### is `&Foo::memberFunction` a pointer?

And there are variations of that.

For instance, if you truly want to know wheter `&Foo::memberFunction` is a pointer, then ask it this way:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_pointer_v<decltype(&Foo::memberFunction)>);
```

and the compiler will tell you something along the lines of

```
Static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_pointer_v<void (Foo::*)()>' [static_assert_requirement_failed]
```

so it just can't match against `FunctionPtrT*`.

As regards

> What is the type of `f` in `bar`?

if you put

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, decltype(f)>);
```

inside of `bar`, the compiler will tell you

```
Static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same_v<void, void (Foo::*)()>'
```

meaning that the type of `f` is `void(Foo::*)()`.

### How does `&Foo::memberFunction`'s type from a free function pointer?

Compare this with the error you get if you define

```cpp
void f();
```

and assert

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, decltype(f)>);
```

The compiiler will tell you

```cpp
Static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same_v<void, void (*)()>'
```

So the point is that `void(*)()`, a pointer to a free function from `void` to `void`, is different from `void (Foo::*)()`, a pointer *member of `Foo`* function from `void` to `void`.

### How can I restrict a template to be instatiated only for member functions?

If you want your template to match only member functions, can go for

```cpp
template<typename InstanceT, typename R, typename C>
void baz(InstanceT&& i, R C::* f) { }
```

or, if you want it to match any member function of `Foo`, you can clearly either change the order of the template parameters such that you can provide `C` manually

```cpp
template<typename C, typename R, typename InstanceT>
void baz(InstanceT&& i, R C::* f) { }
```

which allows you to call `baz<Foo>(/* args */);`, or you can simply hardcode `Foo` in place of `C`:

```
template<typename R, typename InstanceT>
void baz(InstanceT&& i, R Foo::* f) { }
```

### And what if I want to restrict the match to member function with a specific signature?

As you see, we already have a placeholder `R`, for the return type.

If we also wanted to have a placeholder for the arguments, we could go for this:

```cpp
template<typename R, typename C, typename ...Args>
void baz(R (C::*f)(Args...));
```

Which will just match the same function as the previous example. I showed this just to make you see that, if you want to type the arguments out, you *must* put parenthesis around `C::*f`, or just `C::*`, if you want to omit the name (the lack of parenthesis is the typo in the comment under your question). Therefore, if you want to restrict the match to a specific signature, let's say `void()`, this is how you do it:

```cpp
template<typename C>
void baz(void (C::*f)());
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the type of f in bar?

The type of `f` in `bar` is `void (Foo::*)()` i.e., a pointer to a  member function of class `Foo` that has no parameter and has the return type of `void`.

---

The reason `baz(Foo(), &Foo::memberFunction);` fails is that `&Foo::memberFunction` is a pointer to a member function is **distinct** from an ordinary *pointer to some type*.

In fact, [member function pointers are not actually pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167059/are-pointers-to-non-static-member-function-formally-not-considered-pointers).  So the argument of type `void (Foo::*)()` cannot be passed to parameter `FunctionPtrT* f`.