# Forbidden syntax for pointer/reference to bound member function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Suppose I have the following:

```cpp
struct A {
  int foo(int bar) const { return bar; }
};
```

and I want to specify a name that refers to a "bound" member function (i.e.):

```cpp
A a;
auto opt1 = a.foo; // Forbidden, instead do something like...
auto opt2 = [&a] (int i) { return a.foo(i); }; // or ...
auto opt3 = std::bind(&A::foo, a, std::placeholders::_1);
```

it is then simple to invoke the bound member function:

```
assert(opt1(42) == 42); // If 'opt1' were allowed
assert(opt2(42) == 42); 
assert(opt3(42) == 42);
```

In my view, `opt1` would be the preferred solution to achieve the goal.  However, specifying a bound function via `opt1` is forbidden by the language.

My question is purely legal: **What part of the C++(20) standard forbids a construct like `opt1`?**  My question is not *why*, but *where*.

Comment: [Pointers to member functions are not actually pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167059/are-pointers-to-non-static-member-function-formally-not-considered-pointers). They have their own syntax like `&A::foo`. Also, a member function doesn't implicitly decay to pointer to member function unlike ordinary free function.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.ref#6.3.2

Comment: From [basic.compund#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3) *"Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members"* so whatever you assumed about `a.foo` is not true.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this it must to be forbid. It can simply not be a thing like whatever new feature you want.

Comment: @appleapple No, it's explicitly forbidden.

Comment: The syntax you want is: `auto opt1 = &A::foo;` Then it would be called like `(a.*opt1)(42)`.

Comment: @Sneftel I mean OP seems to think anything not explicitly forbit is allowed and has meaningful result.

Comment: @JasonLiam, I didn't assume anything about `a.foo`--I simply wondered where in the standard such a construct was forbidden.  Notice I use the term *name* to specify a bound function, as clearly `opt2` and `opt3` are not pointers.

Comment: @MartinYork, no `auto opt1 = &A::foo` does not specify a *bound* member function.  To bind it to `a`, you would then need to do `(a.*opt1)(42)`.

Comment: Note that the compiler error is: **cannot convert 'A::foo' from type 'int (A::)(int) const' to type 'int (A::*)(int) const'** So `a.foo` seems to be just fine. It's just not an object that can be bound to a name.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel In general there shouldn't be an expectation that something has to be expressly forbidden to not be allowed. Something can be disallowed by omission.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel That's because `foo` is not a member of the objext `a` it is a member of the class `A`. You have to explicitly bind `a` seprately like you have done with `opt2` and `opt3`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, sure, I understand that.  But `a.foo` is so much simpler (in syntax) than the other options that it seemed to me likely that it probably was disallowed...and @Sneftel has found that it is.

Comment: Note2: `&a.foo` yields **ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&A::foo' [-fpermissive]** which is probably a better thing to look for in the standard.

Comment: BTW, `opt2`&`opt3` are not equivalent, one bind by reference, and the later bind by copy (both have syntax to allow the other way). Not sure how `opt1` would have the 2 ways of binding...

Comment: In C++20, another alternative: `auto opt4 = std::bind_front(&A::foo, a);`.

Comment: You could reskin the syntax of C++ to make the syntactic sugar more to your liking.  Such as the [SPECS](https://users.monash.edu/~damian/papers/HTML/ModestProposal.html) (by Werther & Conway) and [Carbon](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang) efforts.  Or you could make your own C++ syntax reskin.  I'm working on one myself, just for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[expr.ref]:

> [for the expression `E1.E2`]....if `E1.E2` refers to a non-static member function...The expression can be used only as the left-hand operand
> of a member function call.