# In what cases does the standard forbid taking pointers to functions/objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, void-pointers, pointer-conversion

This [article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) lists all the different categories of pointers. I have tested the explicit conversion of different types of pointers to `const void*` in the following snippet ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/fnEbj8ae4)):

```
#include <print>


int var {};

void foo()
{
}

struct Bar
{
    char mem;

    void func()
    {
    }
};

Bar b {};

int main()
{
    // nullptr
    std::println( "{}", static_cast<const void*>( nullptr ) );
    // pointer to object
    std::println( "{}", static_cast<const void*>( &var ) );
    // pointer to function
    std::println( "{}", reinterpret_cast<const void*>( &foo ) );
    // pointer to member variable
    std::println( "{}", static_cast<const void*>( &Bar::mem ) ); // doesn't compile
    std::println( "{}", static_cast<const void*>( &(b.mem) ) );
    std::println( "{}", static_cast<const void*>( &(b.*(&Bar::mem)) ) );
    // pointer to member function
    std::println( "{}", reinterpret_cast<const void*>( &Bar::func ) ); // compiles with a warning
    std::println( "{}", reinterpret_cast<const void*>( &(b.func) ) ); // doesn't compile
    std::println( "{}", reinterpret_cast<const void*>( &(b.*(&Bar::func)) ) ); // doesn't compile

    // Did I miss any other category?
}
```

Now I have a few questions:

1. I want to know why `static_cast<const void*>( &Bar::mem ) );` does not compile (since `&(b.*(&Bar::mem))` does). The compiler says:

```
error: invalid 'static_cast' from type 'char Bar::*' to type 'const void*'
```

2. Also I want to know why it's not allowed to take the address of member functions (as seen in the last three statements). The compiler says:

```
ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Bar::func'
```

3. Finally, which pointer types are we allowed to take (at least for trivial tasks like printing) without invoking errors or UB? It seems to me that *pointer to member function* is not allowed.

Comment: in `static_cast<const void*>( &Bar::mem ) )` its not getting the function pointer that fails, but the cast to `const void*`

Comment: please one question per question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai But `&Bar::mem` is not a function pointer. Also, what's the appropriate cast expression then?

Comment: Oh sorry misread. `&Bar::mem` is a pointer to member. But still its not getting the pointer that fails, but the cast

Comment: You should think of `&Bar::mem` as specifying a class offset. It doesn't point to any specific object.

Comment: @doug -- no, don't think of it as a class offset. A pointer-to-member has to be able to handle virtual functions and functions that are defined in virtual bases, neither of which can be stored as a mere offset. The correct mental model is to think of a pointer-to-member-function as a pointer-to-member-function. It simply isn't a pointer.

Comment: Generally speaking, pointers to **data** can be stored in a `void*`; pointers to functions cannot (portably).

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, virtual stuff complicates it. Not a pure fixed offset but a way of locating the member object. Complicated by the usual mental model that a pointer points to a memory location which is not the case here.

Comment: [You cannot cast a pointer-to-member to void * or to any other "regular" pointer type. Pointers-to-members are not addresses the way regular pointers are.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307379/12002570)

Comment: [Are pointers to non-static member function "formally" not considered pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167059/are-pointers-to-non-static-member-function-formally-not-considered-pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to member is different from other pointers. Its not bound to a specific instance, but its rather an offset into a class. Given an instance you can use a pointer to member to get the member. Casting it to `void*` is of no great use, hence C++ does not allow it. Generally C++ is less permissive than C concering casts to `void*`. Hence, `static_cast<const void*>( &Bar::mem ) );` does not compile.

On the other hand `(b.*(&Bar::mem)` uses the instance and the pointer to member to get a reference to the member `mem` of `b`. And `&(b.*(&Bar::mem)` is just the same as `&(b.mem)`. Its a pointer to `b.mem`, a `char*`. You can cast `char*` to `void*`.

(2) and (3) is just about how the syntax is defined.

Comment: This means to get a real pointer to a member variable we need to have an instance of that type. On the other hand, taking the address of a member function is not allowed with/without an instance of the type. The rest of the cases are legal. Am I correct?

Comment: A `void*` typically isn't large enough to hold the data in a ponter-to-member. Even a "simple" pointer-to-member-data is more complicated than it looks, because the data might be in a virtual base, with no fixed offset in the derived type.

Comment: @digito_evo • there's [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to help out with not having an instance of the type — but it has some usage caveats (may make it not suitable for your particular use case in the original question).