# Is it really well defined to check pointer alignment using the pointer's integer value?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Is there a guaranteed (not implementation-defined!) way to check for pointer alignment?

The most common way to query pointer alignment seems to be:

1. convert to integer
2. check whether the integer is a multiple of the alignment:

```cpp
bool is_aligned(void const *ptr, size_t alignment) {
  return reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr) % alignment == 0;
}
```

For example, this is how [Boost.Align checks alignment](https://github.com/boostorg/align/blob/8caa2c0/include/boost/align/detail/is_aligned.hpp#L21).

However, in C++17 at least, [basic.compound#3.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3.4) says:

> The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined.

Furthermore, [expr.reinterpret.cast#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#4) says:

> A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined.

It seems it'd be legal to (for example) represent pointers as integers with reversed bit order, in which case the simple arithmetic above would not work.

AFAICT, the only guaranteed way that we can check alignment is using [`std::align`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/ptr.align), which if read liberally (I'm sure this is an abuse of `std::align`) could be used like so:

```cpp
bool is_aligned(void const *ptr, size_t alignment) {
  void *mut_ptr = const_cast<void *>(ptr);
  size_t space = alignment;
  return std::align(alignment, alignment, mut_ptr, space) == ptr;
}
```

However, on the overwhelming majority of platforms, pointers are just fancy integers, or I'd expect Boost to have a code path for it. Are there any platforms (other than ds9k :P) where pointers *aren't* just fancy integers?

What would we lose by standardizing "`reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr)` shall have the same object representation as `ptr`" or "`reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr) % alignment == 0` if `ptr` is aligned to `alignment`"? It seems neither of those would exclude segmented memory, or pointers with a trap representation, which are two atypical cases I can think of.

If nothing else, is there a reason not to standardize `std::is_aligned()`?

**EDIT:** my specific non-toy use case is I have `std::byte const *ptr;`. The only think I know about `ptr` is that it contains the object representations of 1024 `int`s. How can I check whether it's safe to `reinterpret_cast` `ptr` or use `assume_aligned` on it?

Comment: *It seems it'd be legal to (for example) represent pointers as integers with reversed bit order*  Nice!  **That** is going into my DS9K implementation!  (Better than segmented memory pointers.  But I'm still going to keep banked memory pointers.)

Comment: Is this extra work necessary?  Can I just use `operator &` or `operator %` to determine alignment?  My justification is that if you are using pointers, and need to know alignment, you are probably not aiming for portability and can use platform specifics.

Comment: For example, for an optimized `memcpy(uint8_t *, uint8_t*)`, I can copy 4 bytes at a time if both pointers are 32-bit aligned.

Comment: Not attempting to answer the question (thus posting as a comment rather than an answer), but just a note that `alignof`, `alignas`, `std::aligned_storage` and `std::aligned_union` are all closely related to the question.

Comment: Lovely question! I _think_ your `std::align` solution may have a problem in a situation where `mut_ptr + space` would be outside the original memory segment and aligning the pointer would fall off the edge. Possibly... Hypothetically...

Comment: Sorry, I should've used `reinerpret_cast`. I've added that

Comment: "The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined." Implementation-defined does not mean undefined. If Boost were ported to a different implementation that defines the value representation of pointers differently, *presumably that code would also be changed*.

Comment: @Eljay: You don't need a DeathStation 9000 compiler for that.  Bit-reversed memory access patterns are used in FFT, and some DSP architectures have direct support for bit-reversed pointers.  At least [dsPIC does](https://skills.microchip.com/dsp-features-of-the-microchip-dspic-dsc/694435)

Comment: @BenVoigt A non-DS9000 compiler ought to transform the pointer representation to be an integer of the expected order

Comment: This looks like one of those purely theoretical issues that don't get addressed because they don't get in the way, like the previous lack of `std::launder`. Casting to `uintptr_t` will probably work on every platform.

Comment: @Eljay, I used to have a representation where pointers and integers are XOR 0x20000000, because address 0 is valid RAM.

Comment: @M.M: Although it's likely that such an architecture provides a way to do the bit-reversal efficiently when making a copy of the pointer, it's still an extra step that's doesn't support any of the behaviors specified in the language.

Comment: The Standard I have access to says:
 
'A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type. The
mapping function is implementation-defined. [Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know
the addressing structure of the underlying machine. — end note]'
While that's an intent and not a requirement it would be unhelpful if you can't infer memory alignment from the low bits of an address (as arithmetic type) on platforms where alignment is a thing. So not guaranteed but good implementations would need a good reason not to.

Comment: Interestingly, the concept of alignement in C++ does not mean that addresses must be multiples of some size, but only restricts the *differences* between addresses. So if I am right, checking pointer alignment makes no sense.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It seems it'd be legal to (for example) represent pointers as integers with reversed bit order, in which case the simple arithmetic above would not work.

Yes, nothing forbids that.

Even worse, the mapping can be type-dependent. The only requirement that is implementation-independent is that a round-trip `reinterpret_cast` back to the *original* pointer type results in the original pointer value. And that's maybe not far fetched. For types with high alignment you don't really need to store the zero bits at the end and so the pointer type might be smaller. Then a simple `reinterpret_cast` mapping might not provide any possible information to check alignment for these pointer types. See e.g. [Do all pointers have the same size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870205/do-all-pointers-have-the-same-size-in-c) for discussion on pointer sizes and [Exotic architectures the standards committees care about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about/6986260#6986260) for exotic architectures, at least with regards to C, which also includes examples for this (Cray T90).

Of course, in your use you are using `void*` specifically, which avoids this issue.

It is also possible that no integer type large enough to represent all pointer values exists, in which case `intptr_t` shouldn't be available and `reinterpret_cast` to any integer type will be ill-formed. That's specifically considered in the C standard, so there must have existed such C implementations or it was considered that such implementations may not be unlikely, when `(u)intptr_t` where added to C.

> However, in C++17 at least, basic.compound#3.4 says:

Note that the value representation of the pointer is irrelevant. It isn't required that `reinterpret_cast` leaves the bytes in memory unchanged. So the implementation-defined mapping by `reinterpret_cast` could be completely distinct from how integer and pointer object representations relate.

For example, on 64bit systems often the actual available address space is smaller (e.g. only 48bit). Then there are additional bits in the object representation. I could imagine the compiler/CPU using these extra bits for various purposes. Depending on that purpose the bits may or may not be part of the value representation and they may or may not be stripped or modified by `reinterpret_cast`. Similarly, if a different pointer type instead of `void*` was used, the compiler/CPU could use the bits that are guaranteed to be zero due to alignment requirements of the type for these purposes.

> AFAICT the only guaranteed way that we can check alignment is using std::align, which if read liberally (I'm sure this is abuse of std::align) could be used like so:

The function has undefined behavior if the storage to which the input pointer points isn't contiguously at least `alignment` long the way you wrote it. So the size/space parameters should probably be `1` (or `0`, see [LWG 2421](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2421)) instead. I see nothing in the specification that would require the size to be at least as large as the alignment.

The specification of `std::align` does however seem broken to me anyway, so not sure whether that is intended to work. For example it fails to specify to which (or one-past which) object the resulting pointer points, pretending that it is possible to describe a pointer value just by the address it represents, but that's not possible since C++17.

I think it is also not in line with the definition of *alignment* in [basic] which doesn't assume any integer representation of addresses and only gives restrictions on when an address *satisfies* a *supported* alignment requirement. An implementation that only supports alignment `1` would e.g. be valid and then there is no definition for when an address is aligned for some other power-of-two.

> If nothing else, is there a reason not to standardize std::is_aligned()?

Not that I am aware of. `std::align` seems to have that functionality already as discussed above. A user-friendly wrapper around it would be simple to do, assuming the specification of `std::align` is really as intended and supposed to be guaranteed to work on every implementation.

> EDIT: my specific non-toy use case is I have std::byte const *ptr;. The only think I know about ptr is that it contains the object representations of 1024 ints. How can I check whether it's safe to reinterpret_cast ptr or use assume_aligned on it?

Even if you know that `ptr` is correctly aligned and that the `std::byte` array contains valid object representations for `int`, then it is still not guaranteed that `reinterpret_cast` (which must be followed by `std::launder` either way) will be valid. You also need to make sure that, prior to copying the `int` object representation into the storage, `int` objects have been created. That can happen implicitly, e.g. if you `memcpy` the object representations into the array or use `std::bit_cast` to obtain the filled array into which `ptr` points, but you can't assume it generally. Otherwise you might have an aliasing violation (and/or precondition violation of `std::launder`). In particular if the object representations were copied into the `std::byte` array by a simple per-byte assignment in a loop, then this will result in an aliasing violation.

Comment: A practical example of modern architecture where `intptr_t` (and `uintptr_t`) are more than a memory address is CHERI. In CHERI, the pointer is 128-bits, with a 64-bits opaque value and a 64-bits memory address, hence `intptr_t` is 128 bits to satisfy the round-trip requirement. I expect that the lower 8 bytes of that are the memory address... but I'm not sure there's any guarantee.

Comment: I do want to note that being the represent the memory address itself in a 64bits integer doesn't imply the memory address is stored in the lower-bits of the 128bits integer. Of course, in practice, the goal is to make CHERI practical, and that implies trying to make it as easy to integrate in existing codebase, and thus having the memory address in the lower bits is easier for everyone involved.

Comment: Interesting. `std::uintptr_t` is 128bit there, but it is still possible to represent the pointer value in a 64bit integer, which (assuming the integers behave standard-conforming) is indeed the lower bits of the equivalent 128bit integer and pointer representation, at least on the implementation that the following compiler explorer link uses: https://cheri-compiler-explorer.cl.cam.ac.uk/z/aWYx8W. So the standard implementation shown in the question still works there (for supported alignments, definitively not for alignments > 2^63)

Comment: Clang has a `__builtin_is_aligned` function for this reason: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

While I was porting the CMocka test library to support CHERI, I actually used Clang's `__builtin_align_down` align a pointer value properly: https://gitlab.com/cmocka/cmocka/-/commit/0559ef6e8ea2acdeaea9d224f634a54b2258cb42 It's not standard C, but only Clang supports CHERI currently, so it's not too big of a deal if it only works on the Clang compiler.